# Correctly formatting currencies to more decimal places than the Locale specifies

Tags: java, android, localization, locale

In France and other countries, the currency symbol is after a monetary amount while in others it is before, plus, the decimal separator is a comma rather than a point (`£0.00` vs `0,00 €`).

If I use the following Java code (from memory, may not compile) on my Android device, I can get a `NumberFormat` which formats things correctly:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Currency.get(Locale.FRANCE));
```

This `NumberFormat` formats to the correct number of decimal places (two in the above examples).

I would like to format to 10 decimal places for a financial app, while keeping the decimal separator and 'symbol side' correct.

I can quite happily build my own format expression - the problem is finding out the information for a particular `Locale` or `Country`. Is there a way of finding this out at runtime from the Java/Dalvik VMs or am I just going to have to hard code it?

Hard coding it isn't really a problem as I only have about 20 currencies to worry about, but obviously if it can be derived then that is even easier :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [NumberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)) and [NumberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits(int)) to control how many decimal places are shown.